# Parse current user and query creates bad access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, parse-platform

When I get the current user and then query my database in Parse, a bad access error appears. The code is in the viewDidLoad method. This is not all of the code in the viewDidLoad method. If more code is needed to diagnose the problem I will post it. I do not understand why this problem is happening. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
//Set table view delegate and data source
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

//Set status bar style
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

//Customize the tab bar
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.59 green:0.21 blue:0.21 alpha:1.0];

//Get the current user
currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
    if ([currentUser[@"role"] isEqualToString:@"UserOne"]) {
        //Array
        self.profiles = [NSMutableArray array];
        PFQuery *queryForProfiles = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [queryForProfiles whereKey:@"gender" equalTo:currentUser[@"gender"]];
        [queryForProfiles whereKey:@"role" equalTo:@"UserTwo"];
        [queryForProfiles whereKey:@"location" equalTo:currentUser[@"location"]];
        [queryForProfiles findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    //Add user to profiles array
                    [self.profiles addObject:object];
                }
                //Update the table view
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}

self.tableView.layer.opacity = 0.0;

//Role of User
roleOfUser = currentUser[@"role"];
```

The error occurs at the line that starts the block for the query. [queryForProfiles findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

Comment: So, *where* does the error occur???

Comment: The error occurs at the line that starts the block for the query. [queryForProfiles findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

Comment: Where is the exception traceback showing that?

Comment: That's the last line before the app crashes.

Comment: And it says LookUpImpOrForward on the left as the last call.

Comment: Where is the exception stack trace?

Comment: I can't post images my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: Don't post an image.  Copy/paste the exception stack trace from the log.

Comment: Here is the stack trace.  2014-12-27 21:52:46.336 MyApp[4493:674586] (
 0   MyApp                            0x000000010003c6c0 main + 64
 1   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000196cbaa08 <redacted> + 4
)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query? You've set three variables to return. Are you just trying to get the current user or one specific item?

Comment: I'm trying to get all of the users that fit that criteria: the gender of the current user, the role of that user is UserTwo, and the location of the user is the same as the current user's. Then I take those and display it in a table view.

Comment: shadowme, for future reference if you want to replay to someone make sure you put the @ symbol in front of their name so they get notified. but there are a couple fundamental things wrong here. Your queries are counter productive. you can't query the column gender against gender it has to be something like whereKey:@"gender" equalTo:@"Male" i suggest you look at subqueries in the Parse documentation it will save you some headaches

Comment: @soulshined I am querying the column gender of another user in the database against the current users value.

Comment: I don't know, i think i'm just confused by everything, maybe if you take a screenshot of your parse backend and supply it (blocking out any personal information of course) I'm willing to help you through it though. Parse is my main squeeze

Comment: I can't post screenshots, my reputation is too low. Is there an email or some other sort of communication I can contact you at? My email is pokobros@gmail.com. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: since you don't even have enough reputation to chat i will contact you here shortly. fyi you can post links to pics on dropbox or where ever you put them

Comment: Quick Question: Have you imported the required frameworks for this? (http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/connect-your-swift-application-to-parse-com/) - If so, have you checked that there are definitely users in the parse database?

Comment: Don't post screenshots -- copy/paste text into your question.  Format it with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

Shadowme,

I'm sorry, a horrible mistake on my part. Your code was visually full I kind of skimmed through it too fast. You can't query the user class the way you have structured it.

To query a user class you simply do the following:

```
PFQuery *queryForProfiles = [PFUser query];
```

Comment: @shadowme Then you have other issues. I will email you. However, this is the correct syntax for querying user class